# How to Do a Multiselect Using Gridview Conrol?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm going to use a gridview control as a list. How can I do a multiselect without using any button or anything because I need to pass all values of my gridview to a string or a list of array I think? I'm using ASP.Net C#. How can I possibly do this?

Comment: Why are you using a gridview and not a listbox or a listview? they have a multiple selection, which you can pass as a list of strings to whatever you need...

Comment: How to use a listbox or a listview instead? Can you provide me sample codes for the both of them? So that I can choose what control is best for my system.